# Php simplexml loop is putting the simple element into array. How do I get rid of it?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

This is how the array comes out

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "174" [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) { [0]=> string(2) "41" } [2]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) { [0]=> string(2) "21" } }
```

I'm using this code here that generates the array.

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){

 $values[] = $row['id'];

    $dom = simplexml_load_file('../data/'.$row['id'].'.xml');
    foreach($dom->children() as $child)
  {
  $values[] = $child->views;
  }

  }
  var_dump($values);
```

The xml file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<website site_id="174" user_id="26">
  <view day="23" month="10" year="11">
    <views>31</views>
  </view>
  <view day="23" month="12" year="11">
    <views>21</views>
  </view>
</website>
```

I need to get the value of the Views into an array, but I keep getting these annoying 
**object(SimpleXMLElement)#5** things in the array. Also this **string(3)** . How do I get rid of those. 
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to change

```
$values[] = $child->views;
```

with

```
$values[] = (string)$child->views;
```

> How do I get rid of those

If you don't need to see the type of the variable - just don't use `var_dump()`, but `print_r()` instead

To explain (string): This is called 'typecasting'. Also works with other types such as (int), (bool), etc.